# Using Widget Logic to place menu on multiple pages?

Tags: plugins, widgets

So I have 5 main navigation areas, and I am trying to have each sections pages have their own specific left sidebar/menu.

For example, all pages in the 'about' section should use the 'about menu'. I've got Widget logic working for one page using

is_page('about')

That works for that one page. I tried to use is_array( listing the page names) but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your code? Else it is hard to help. Btw, I guess you meant to use the function `in_array()` not `is_array()`.

Comment: According to the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/installation/), no code changes are required.

Comment: Putting `is_page( 'about' )` somewhere is a code change.

Comment: is_page ('about') is the entirety of the code that is entered onto the widget.

Comment: Then you are asking about inputting code into the third party plugin's widget which renders the question off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if(is_page("about")){

.... do aomething...; 

}elseif(is_page("contact")){

...do aomething...; 

}elseif (...){

... 


}. . .
```